# How to transform a column from a gridview in a dropdownlist with 2 values to choose

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview with the following columns:

```
NAME|AGE|Birthday|Code
Joh  21   12.12.2 Yes/No
```

Currently the column code is a textbox. How can I transform it into a dropdownlist with 2 values: Yes/No so if I press edit I can choose in that cell the Value Yes or No.

Also How can I check on edit event too see if value is yes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template field like this:

```
   <columns>     

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID ="ddlCode" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  CssClass="DropDn1" />     
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
```

In your rowdatabound event of the grid you will bind it if you want to bind from the database.

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
 DropDownList code= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCode") as DropDownList;
                    if (code!= null)
                    {
                       //Bind the dropdownlist
                    }
}
```

To retrieve the value from the dropdown in your edit event you will do this:

```
string code = (row.FindControl("ddlCode") as DropDownList).Text);
```